Cloud run seems to timeout and generate HTTP 304 responses for application endpoints that don't check last modified headers or other etags
I have a Rails application on cloud run with an endpoint called by our apps to determine if their version is current and if not, requires a download. This is a simple, one record read of the database in a table of less than one hundred records and the vast majority of the time the endpoint returns in a few milliseconds. According to the logs most of the time the records is read form SQL cache and the SQL query and system insights never show any load or locks on the DB.
For some reason this endpoint and a few others occasionally return an HTTP 304 response after 20 to 25 seconds (!). I never see any attempt to access the database ( or anything else ) by the code in these cases. Simply a one line entry in the log of a GET with an absurdly large response time.
I'm expecting a normal sub-second response
EDIT It appears I was incorrect about no activity. I was confused by the log output. Here is an example from today. The initial call appears in the log at 14:50:37, there is additional log output then processing actually begins 20 seconds laterlog snippet

Please define "occasionally". What proportion of requests return 304s? And what proportion of those take secs? It would be helpful if you could update your question to include as much of the request and response with status code 304 that you're able including headers. What and where is the database? Do you use any tracing?

Thanks -  I checked yesterday's logs and this happened 9 times in about 14K requests. It's a low volume site but ramping up gradually and I'd like to get a handle on it

I'm not being dismissive of your concern but trying to quantify/understand it.

It appears I was incorrect there is DB activity taking place but i was confused by the log output ( and now am even more mystified ). Here is an example from today:
